# RTL8723BE 14.04 Kernel 3.19.0-26 Log in prompts

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, kernel, realtek-wireless

I'm having some trouble getting wifi to work on a HP latptop  using RTL8723BE.

I've followed the solutions in regards to Pilot's drivers

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware`

I've also enabled the following option in modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf

`echo "options rtl8723be msi=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723b3.conf
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N msi=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf`

It seems to work, connection is stable but I'm unable to ping any sites and am occasionally prompted with log in screen. My wifi settings are WPA2PSK-AES.

However, `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=0` this param allowed it to connect but from my understanding its for Intel drivers :s.

If you require more info I can provide it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed! Ended up doing an update through wired to kernel 3.19-36 and after kernel update wifi started to work. Thank you Pilot for the DKMS drivers and your help around the forums.